# Perl - interpolate JSON string values

Tags: json, perl

I have a json file like this:

```
"tool_name": {
    "command": "$ENV{TOOL_BIN_DIR}/some_file_name",
    "args": "some args"
}
```

I am using `use:JSON` from Perl 5.14. and using `decode_json` function to read the file and get data into perl hash.

But when I refer to this read data from code like this:

```
my $cmd = "$data->{tool_name}->{command}";
print $cmd;
```

I get

```
$ENV{TOOL_BIN_DIR}/some_file_name
```

How can I make perl resolve the value of this variable?

This example uses enviornment variable but in general if I want to use variables from JSON - how can I do that?

Comment: Is your file supposed to be some kind of config file? Do you need to support other Perl syntax besides string interpolation of environment variables?

Comment: What problem are you having? Where's your code? Are you asking us to write a template processor for you???

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes this is a config file. No that is all I need

Comment: @ikegami : No, I am simply asking if there is a way to interpolate the perl strings stored in JSON as strings

Comment: What a "Perl string"? You mean a Perl string literal? `$ENV{TOOL_BIN_DIR}/some_file_name` isn't valid Perl, string literal or otherwise. If you did have valid Perl, you could execute it, yes. It would be really "unwise" to store Perl code in a config file, though. Instead, you have a custom template language. You will therefore need a custom template parser and processor. You should use an *existing* template language.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a separate environment variable for the full path to the binary? e.g. `TOOL_BIN`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : Lets say instead of env variable I am using something like: $bin_dir. All I want is to have perl interpolate the value of this $bin_dir and get the actual value instead of literally "$bin_dir"

Comment: Re "*All I want is ...*", That's not all. What if you wanted to produce `$bin_dir`? You also need an escaping mechanism. /// Re "*All I want is to have perl interpolate the value of this $bin_dir*", Again, what problem are you having?

Comment: I can not modify the json file, that is my problem. All i can do is read it and have my perl code interpolate it

Comment: Not ideal; it means more work for you since you can't use someone else's parser. What have done so far? What problem are you having?

Comment: Why can't you modify the JSON file? Where does it come from?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : its from another tool. I do not have permissions to edit that file. 
ikegami : This is not about what is ideal. This is about solution to my problem which i have already written down and other users are already able to understand my problem. Feel free to close the thread if you think this is not correct

Comment: if I do "print $cmd", perl is not resolving the value of $ENV{TOOL_BIN_DIR}, it is printing with this literal string "$ENV{TOOL_BIN_DIR}" not its value. This is my problem

Comment: And the other tool generates arbitrary Perl code and puts it in JSON strings? (I hope this doesn't feel like an interrogation, I'm really just trying to figure out what your setup is.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : yes you are correct. someone owns the tool that creates this json file and is largely based on environment variables. Unfortunately the system is rigid and i can not ask for more :(

Comment: Re "*This is my problem*", That's a specification, not a problem. What problem are you having writing the code to do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `eval` opens you to up to malicious or accidental damage: the string you are executing could contain any Perl code that may do anything at all to your system

It is preferable to use `interpolate` from the [`String::Interpolate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Interpolate) module, which uses Perl's own interpolation engine that expands ordinary double-quoted strings at run time

This program sets up a value for the environment variable `TOOL_BIN_DIR` and expands all the values in the `tool_name` hash that contain a dollar `$` or at `@` sigil

I've used `Data::Dump` to display the contents of the data after the interpolation

You may want to write a recursive subroutine that will process the values of all nested hashes and arrays if you don't know which values are likely to contain a value that needs to be expanded

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use JSON 'decode_json';
use String::Interpolate 'interpolate';
use Data::Dump 'dd';

my $data = decode_json <<'__END_JSON__';
{
    "tool_name": {
        "command": "$ENV{TOOL_BIN_DIR}/some_file_name",
        "args": "some args"
    }
}
__END_JSON__

$ENV{TOOL_BIN_DIR} = 'tool_dir_test';

for ( values %{ $data->{tool_name} } ) {
    $_ = interpolate($_) if /[\$\@]/;
}

dd $data;
```

#### output

```
{
  tool_name => { args => "some args", command => "tool_dir_test/some_file_name" },
}
```

Comment: Re "*uses Perl's own interpolation engine*", That's awful! `perl -MString::Interpolate=interpolate -e'CORE::say interpolate($ARGV[0])' '${ print "I just deleted all your files\n"; \"x" }'`. Don't execute config files!

Comment: There's also `safe_interpolate`, but that still leaves enough opcodes to do a DOS attack, for example. Better not to execute anything at all.

Answer (score -2):

You can use eval like in:

```
my $cmd = '$ENV{HOME}/toto';
print eval('"' . $cmd . '"'), "\n";
```

But remember, this is very unsafe from a security point of view. You should probably avoid having to do this.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Better way would be to interpolate the value directly.

Comment: @Deadman This is as direct as it gets. All you have is a string; you need to somehow tell perl to parse the string as Perl code and to execute it, which is exactly what string `eval` does.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Thanks a lot @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: That's awful! Fails if the string contains `"`. There's also this: `perl -e'CORE::say eval(q{"} . $ARGV[0] . q{"})' '${ print qq{I just deleted all your files\n}; \qq{x} }'`. Don't execute config files!

Comment: Just two remarks for people who downvoted me: module String::Interpolate contains calls to eval function and perl interpolation can already be used to delete all your file. I think my warnings were clear enough.